# How do I disable fetching of DEP-11 files

Tags: apt, updates, software-center, downloads

I noticed, In 16.04, `apt-get update` downloads more data. Some of the big files include `DEP-11` things which I don't know much about.

I have found a Debian Wiki page https://wiki.debian.org/AppStream, which says these files YAML-formatted metadata provided for ---

> The metadata can for example be used by software centers like GNOME Software or KDE Discover to display a user-friendly application-centric way on the package archive.

But, I don't use these Software Centers and I don't want to fetch those huge files. How do I disable fetching of these wastes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like it is defined in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream`

Can be disabled with:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream{,.disabled}
```

That stopped it on mine, still visible in updates as:

> `N: Ignoring file '50appstream.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension`

Edit:

If you want, you can just move the file outside of that directory, it will no longer show up. No more notices.  eg:`sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream /etc/apt/50appstream`

Comment: Isn't It an error?

Comment: Well, the "N:" part means it's just a notice. You get "W:" warnings as well. Actual errors stop it functioning.

Answer (score 31):

If you dont need graphical package manager you can uninstall `appstream` package and all graphical managers that depend on it:

```
aptitude purge appstream
```

If you prefer `mv` solution, then better do it with `dpkg-divert` and it will stay persistent on package upgrades:

```
dpkg-divert --local --rename --divert '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/#50appstream' /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50appstream
```

Comment: That's probably _two_ answers, but both are better than the accepted answer :-)