# Offline Repository `sudo apt update fails` with cannot file icon 64x64 error

Tags: apt, 20.04, repository, offline

I created an offline repository for Ubuntu 20.04 using the instructions provided in [this link](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-a-ubuntu-repository-server) as it is. No changes there.

But, I create the sources.list file using `file:///` notation instead of `http://` notation, which gave me the following errors

Note: I have omitted some lines in the output because of SO restrictions, but I guess the question maintains it's essence and meaning.

### File Notation

File: sources.list

```
deb file:///var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb file:///var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
deb file:///var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb file:///var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
deb file:///var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb file:///var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
deb file:///var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Output:

```
Get: 1 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
Get: 2 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
Get: 3 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [111 kB]

Get: 10 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [29.5 kB]
Ign file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata

Get: 13 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/restricted Translation-en [6,212 B]
Ign file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/restricted Translation-en

Get: 23 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [970 kB]
Get: 24 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [718 kB]
Get: 25 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main Translation-en [506 kB]
Get: 26 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [29.5 kB]
Get: 27 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/restricted i386 Packages [8,112 B]
Get: 28 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 Packages [22.0 kB]
Get: 29 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/restricted Translation-en [6,212 B]
Get: 30 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [392 B]
Get: 31 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages [8,628 kB]
Get: 32 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages [4,642 kB]
Get: 33 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/universe Translation-en [5,124 kB]

Get: 36 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages [144 kB]
Get: 37 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/multiverse Translation-en [104 kB]
Get: 38 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [9,136 B]
Get: 39 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [930 kB]
Ign file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages

Get: 60 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [1,179 kB]
Ign file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Get: 61 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/multiverse i386 Packages [88.9 kB]
Ign file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/multiverse i386 Packages
Get: 62 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [32.3 kB]
Ign file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Get: 63 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [930 kB]
Get: 64 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [111 kB]
Err file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  File not found - /var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/cnf/Commands-amd64 (2: No such file or directory)
Get: 65 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/restricted i386 Packages [10.1 kB]
Ign file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/restricted i386 Packages
Get: 66 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [196 kB]
Get: 67 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [326 kB]
Get: 68 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/main Translation-en [123 kB]

Ign file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Get: 86 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [103 kB]
Ign file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
Get: 87 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [19.6 kB]
Ign file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata

Get: 89 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [1,555 B]
Ign file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Get: 90 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [248 kB]
Get: 91 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [29.9 kB]
Err file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  File not found - /var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/cnf/Commands-amd64 (2: No such file or directory)
...
Get: 111 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-backports/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [59 B]
Ign file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-backports/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Get: 112 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [53 B]
Err file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  File not found - /var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/main/cnf/Commands-amd64 (2: No such file or directory)
Get: 113 file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-backports/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [59 B]
Ign file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-backports/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease: Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/cnf/Commands-amd64: File not found - /var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/cnf/Commands-amd64 (2: No such file or directory)
W: Failed to fetch file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/cnf/Commands-amd64: File not found - /var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/cnf/Commands-amd64 (2: No such file or directory)
W: Failed to fetch file:/var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/main/cnf/Commands-amd64: File not found - /var/www/html/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/main/cnf/Commands-amd64 (2: No such file or directory)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`
```

[image: Ign folders]
and
[image: Ign 2]

When I tried with `http://`, I tried full address and local address

### Static IP [Internet IP]

IP changed from the actual value.

I get that the address was not found.
File: sources.list

```
deb http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
deb http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
deb http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
deb http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Output is:

```
Get: 1 http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]

Get: 5 http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [718 kB]
Get: 6 http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [718 kB]
Get: 7 http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [718 kB]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease        
  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Get: 8 http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [718 kB]
Get: 9 http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [718 kB]
Get: 10 http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [718 kB]
Get: 11 http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [718 kB]
Get: 12 http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [718 kB]
Get: 13 http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [718 kB]
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Get: 14 http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/restricted i386 Packages [8,112 B]
Get: 15 http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/restricted i386 Packages [8,112 B]
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Get: 16 http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages [4,642 kB]
Get: 17 http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages [4,642 kB]
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
Get: 18 http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [265 kB]
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Get: 19 http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/multiverse i386 Packages [74.7 kB]
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata

Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata

Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Get: 20 http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [930 kB]
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages

Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-backports/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-backports/universe i386 Packages
Get: 21 http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-backports/universe Translation-en [1,448 B]
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata

Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Err http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  404  Not Found [IP: 154.11.35.52 80]
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal/multiverse i386 Packages
Err http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  404  Not Found [IP: 154.11.35.52 80]
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-backports/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-backports/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Err http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  404  Not Found [IP: 154.11.35.52 80]
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-backports/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-backports/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Fetched 475 kB in 0s (1,044 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease: Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/cnf/Commands-amd64: 404  Not Found [IP: 154.11.35.52 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/cnf/Commands-amd64: 404  Not Found [IP: 154.11.35.52 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://154.11.35.52/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/main/cnf/Commands-amd64: 404  Not Found [IP: 154.11.35.52 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

[image]

### Static IP local/loopback

I get the following,

File: sources.list

```
deb http://10.0.0.1/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb http://10.0.0.1/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
deb http://10.0.0.1/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://10.0.0.1/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
deb http://10.0.0.1/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://10.0.0.1/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
deb http://10.0.0.1/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

The output is

```
  Could not connect to 10.0.0.1:80 (10.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err http://10.0.0.1/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to 10.0.0.1:http:
Err http://10.0.0.1/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to 10.0.0.1:http:
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://10.0.0.1/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease: Could not connect to 10.0.0.1:80 (10.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Failed to fetch http://10.0.0.1/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease: Unable to connect to 10.0.0.1:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://10.0.0.1/ubuntu/mirror/mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease: Unable to connect to 10.0.0.1:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease: Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

[image: Loopback error]
The error is a lot smaller, that is the number of repositories read is also seems to be smaller.

How do I make the apt-mirror repository work as an offline repository for the system itsself and make it as a server for Intranet connection systems. (i.e., it will have a local IP)

---

Edit:

https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/issues/113
This link seems to have a relevant discussion, but I don't know if it is solving the problem.

---

This seems like a huge issue:
https://gist.github.com/benjaoming/28b8ddc9f0ee6ef74d113625bd667d90
https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qt5/+/281447
[How do I disable fetching of DEP-11 files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823329/how-do-i-disable-fetching-of-dep-11-files)
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTQAINFRA-3351
https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/issues/113

---

I tried this: https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/pull/103

---

Other solutions, won't fix my problem, but available.
https://github.com/flavienbwk/debmirror
https://github.com/flavienbwk/apt-mirror-docker

I don't know how to use them.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting.

Comment: @muru I have added the formatted text, instead of just screenshots.

Comment: I've updated the problem with many links which discuss some of the issues I face.

Comment: Seems to me your only actual problem is the missing `Commands-amd64` files. See dupe for that. The links seem to be for similar-looking but different issues.

Comment: what do you mean by dupe?

Comment: I found something, I'm unable to figure out if it is the solution https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/issues/118 and https://salsa.debian.org/debian/debmirror/-/tree/master/debian

Comment: I feel like, my question is much more comprehensive with links and I'm refusing to delete it. If the mods feel like this question shouldn't exist, I shall be happy to oblige.

Comment: As mentioned, I have tried the solution given in this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252828/apt-mirror-for-amd64-did-not-include-focal-main-dep11-and-focal-main-cnf-command link and I shall update if I solve the problem.

Comment: It did solve my problem, with one update. I added [arch=amd64] for each of my source.list

Comment: It did not completely fix my problem, there was some issue regarding 404 Server not found for some files. And some files are being downloaded.